# Mapstruct and @Cacheable

Tags: mapstruct

I have a class annotated with an `org.mapstruct.Mapper` and attempting to use an `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable` annotation on a method. That method is also annotated with `org.mapstruct.Named`.
The `@Cacheable` annotation is being ignored.
Is it possible to use `@Cacheble` on a Mapstruct `@Mapper` method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible cause it seems that the mapstruct processor is filtering that annotation out. But you can inject a bean and cache the method of the bean like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public abstract class Mapper {

@Autowired
protected Bean bean;

@Named("someNamedMethod")
public Object doSomething() {
  return bean.doSomeMagic()
}

@Component
public class Bean {

@Cacheable(your params)
public Object doSomething() {
  your code... }
}
```